# Implementing Google Maps Autocomplete in SlickGrid

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, slickgrid

Has anyone successfully accomplished this? I would like to initialize the autocomplete in a SlickGrid cell. I suspect that fashioning an autocomplete editor may be the way to go.

The cells don't have a DOM id but I have been able to use a getElementsByClassName('slick-cell l5 r5 cell-title active selected'), which is the cell that my Address column is in. I have seen where others have implemented an Autocomplete editor supplying a list but I can't seem to get either of these methods to work with the Google Maps Autocomplete code.

I'm fairly new to SlickGrid but have managed to accomplish many other things successfully except this one. Anyone pulled this off?

Comment: Please provide some code....also you can assign different id to each slickgrid row and cell in slick.grid.js where rows are created like `$("<div class='slick-row' />").appendTo($canvas);` and then access it

Comment: I want to implement the autocomplete functionality to a cell, not a row. It would have to work when the cell is in edit mode on key press.

The usual means of attaching the autocomplete is by Id.

    `var input = document.getElementById('primary-address'); // this is the usual way of implementing the autocomplete functionality to an element

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);`